# Which 2x4 gb modules Ram is compatible with an Asrock H55M-LE?

Tags: memory

I've bought from Amazon [this](http://www.amazon.it/HyperX-Fury-Memorie-1866-Nero/dp/B00J8E90I2/ref=sr_1_1?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1447246066&sr=1-1&keywords=ram%202x4%201866) Ram that seems to be incompatible with my AsRock H55M-LE. 
I've returned it (with 2 modules installed, system and bios won't start, with only one module installed, system start but windows crash and reboot).

My problem is to know which Ram that it sold today, is compatible with H55M-LE.

[In the manual](http://www.asrock.com/mb/memory/H55M-LE.pdf) i can see tested models, but 4gb models tested is out of the market or cost a lot (100$ bucks for 4gb!).

Anyone who own this motherboard can help me to find some compatible ram maybe sold by Amazon ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any basic DDR3 1333 sticks should work. There's no particular concern unless you're going for crazy overclocks.

Specific hardware recommendations are out of scope for SU. Just find any sticks that are 1.5v, 1333 or 1600Mhz, 2x4G not 1x8GB and should be fine. Also RESET the bios before you insert them.

Update: based on comments:
You run an Intel® Core™ i3-550 which according to ARK supports a maximum memory clock of 1333Mhz.

Comment: So do you think incompatibily was due to 1866mhz ram clock ? I know at the moment i'm using 1333mhz ram, but i would like to buy 1600 ..hope will be compatible !

Comment: RAM speed has an imperceptible difference for the *vast* majority of users.  "Note1: DDR3-2000, 2133, 2200 and 2600 are only optimized for Core i7 860 and i7 870 Note4: DDR3-1800 are only optimized with discrete card when use Clarkdale CPU."  -  What CPU are you using?

Comment: intel core i3-550 3.2ghz

Comment: @stighy I've added an update to my answer

Comment: Oh, so the problem was the cpu. But in Ark i can see1066/1333 not 1600... are you sure 1600 ? Thanks again

Comment: @stighy Derp, I shouldnt multitask. Really the memory should downclock to match the CPU but with XMP etc that doesnt always go smoothly.

Comment: The specializations on the CPU indicate the stock frequency of the memory.  Check the motherboard to indicate what higher frequency the motherboard itself supports via overclocking.

Comment: @Ramhound Mobo qualified vendor list specifies higher clocks were only recommended for use with certain chips.

Comment: @Linef4ult - Of course which is the reason I pointed back to the specifications.  He specifically talks about the frequency on the ark page though.